# How to apply ScrollBar and ListBoxItem styles on only one ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a style that targets any `ScrollBar` by the `Key` in the app.xaml:

```
x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
```

but the problem is that it's applied on any scroll bar in the application, the same happens for the `ListBoxItem`. How to apply it on only one ListBox, so I can use a string-based key, for example, I'm looking for something like this AP in the `ListBox`

```
ScrollBar.Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add an explicit `Style` to `<ListBox.Resources>`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    ...
</ListBox>
```